# Gnuplot+epslatex irregular dashed line

Tags: gnuplot, epslatex

I'm using gnuplot+epslatex to generate some plots.

This is what I put in the gnuplot code

```
set terminal epslatex color size xwidth cm,1.1*xwidth font 9 header 
\fontsize{10}{13.2} 
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}' 
dashlength 2.0 round standalone

set output "energy14two.tex"
```

and then I generate the .ps using this script

```
#!/bin/bash
gnufilename=$1
name=`grep "set *output" $1 | grep -v \# | awk '{print $3}' | cut -b 1 --complement | rev | cut -b 1 --complement | rev`
texfilename=${name%.*}
gnuplot $gnufilename && { latex -halt-on-error $texfilename.tex && dvips -q $texfilename.dvi && rm $texfilename.dvi; rm $texfilename-inc.eps $texfilename.aux $texfilename.log $texfilename.tex; }
```

For the curve I used a dashed line style, and when I open the `.ps` file I find that the dashes length is quite irregular.
Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the `postscript` terminal (which is used by the `epslatex` terminal). It uses relative coordinates when drawing the plot lines. Since this may give rounding errors, a moveto is issued every 100 points. This interrupts the path, which becomes visible when using dash patterns.

The `cairolatex eps` terminal shouldn't have this problem (The pdfcairo terminal doesn't have this problem, so the `cairolatex` terminal should also work fine).